# Transfer a Windows 8 license from a netbook to a laptop

Tags: windows-8, license, migration

I recently treated myself to a new laptop and then realised that it came with Windows 8 Core, not [Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Editions).

However, a while back when it was first released, I bought a Windows 8 Pro License while it was on offer (£25 I think). I installed this on my Windows 7 netbook to play with. What I am wondering is if I restore my netbook to Windows 7, can I use that license to upgrade my new laptop to Windows 8 Pro?

Bearing in mind I have already installed the 120+ updates to bring it up to Windows 8.1.

I'm just wondering if I can get a decisive answer before wiping my netbook, as I've read many contradictory sites whilst trying to find an answer.

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade the Core license to Professional and skip installing Windows 7?

Comment: because apparently that would cost another £99

Comment: I don't know where you say that.  You should be able to use the license to do a clean install over Windows 8 Core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a retail license and you do actually revert the original machine to Windows 7, then yes, you can.

If you bought the license as OEM or you fail to revert the original machine back to Windows 7, then no, you can't.

It is as simple as that.

Comment: I downloaded it direct from Microsoft, so I guess that would make it  a retail license rather than OEM, right?

Comment: Indeed it would.  This means you are very much ok to transfer the license :)

Comment: that's great cheers, time to wipe my netbook then.